The SVN working copy is too old while uploading it to PBaas
I tried uploading the SVN copy io_ecutest to the PBaaS database, and then the below message popped up
Error Message: The working copy at 'C:\Workspace\io_ecutest <file:///C:/Workspace/io_ecutest> ' is too old (format 29) to work with client version '1.14.1-SharpSvn (SharpSvn/1.14.1)' (expects format 31)


I tried upgrading the SVN working copy but the content is getting changed and the io_ecutest is not working properly

Upgrading the format of a working copy doesn’t change its versioned content. And if the format of the working copy isn’t compatible with your client, you have to upgrade it (that’s what the error message is saying).
